# HTML not showing up on browser

Tags: php

I am writing a code in which the user is asked for username and password. If the details provided  match the details in the database, then he is displayed the data, else he is prompted with a message that the information provided is not valid. 
Here is the part of the code that says information is not valid,

```
<?php if($user!=$username && $pass!=$password)
  {          
?>
<p id="intro">Invalid Information</p>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

But the problem I am facing is that even if the username and password does not match, the message Invalid Information is not displayed. Please help out. Thanks

Comment: Does `!==` in place `!=` help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need OR, not AND:

```
<?php if($user!=$username || $pass!=$password) : ?>
<p id="intro">Invalid Information</p>
<?php endIf; ?>
```

P.S. I used the alternative syntax. It looks better.

---

The reasoning for using OR and not AND, if you check for AND, only if **both** username **AND** password is wrong, the condition will evaluate to true (if one of them is correct, you will get FALSE).

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems to be wrong. as you are using not equals to compare with the both variables, so to what you are trying to get from the logic, you have to use || instead of &&.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php if($user!=$username && $pass!=$password)
   {          
echo '<p id="intro">Invalid Information</p>';
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the id `intro`would work within the echo tag? I have seen that it works if its a `span`. Have no idea about the `p` tag.

Comment: @StartupCrazy its just a print instruction - it will work with every tag, just ensure not to mix up quotes